# OBJ Loader for OpenGL + Glut

Tags: opengl, loader, freeglut

I'm working on a game for open GL, and I want to simply be able to load OBJ files, with their textures into my game. I want the loader to contain all the necessary code to map the textures to the object.

(Note I have scoured google, and not one example I've seen has been simple enough to bolt onto my currently existing code, I'm talking 2 headers, and 2 cpps maximum)

Could anybody provide me with one?

Comment: [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) is the usual choice. It's a bigger library, but I don't see how that's a problem...

Answer (score 3):

you could get started by this simple loader which loads objects in a wavefront .obj file into a OpenGL scene. This code restricts to just scanning the vertex information out of OBJ. You could enhance it further may be after getting the basic idea.

http://netization.blogspot.in/2014/10/loading-obj-files-in-opengl.html

https://github.com/nanosmooth/opengl_objloader

Answer (score 1):

You can find mine at: https://github.com/NewbiZ/sandbox/tree/master/mar_tp1

It's a pretty simple one, but clean.

you will only need the `Model` class, which will load an OBJ file by filename: https://github.com/NewbiZ/sandbox/blob/master/mar_tp1/inc/mar_tp1/model.h

You may need to remove some things to make it fit on your project. Namely the dependency to `ResourceManager` which loads the textures and return their id, but that should not be much work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you kindly Sir, I'll update you on how it goes =)

Comment: How would I go about calling the loader from another method?

(My apologies, I haven't been coding all that long)

Also, would the parameter for that method call be the path of the obj file?

Comment: Hey man, I'm having an issue wit the load method, it keeps returning false and not loading the object,  exactly what parameters should I place into the load method?

Like the whole path + file name and extension? Apologies for bothering you so much.

Comment: Hey! Just look at the comments in the code :)      * \param data_path         Path from where to look for textures (when processing MTL)
     * \param mesh_filename     Path to the OBJ file
     * \param material_filename Path to the MTL file
     * \return true if the model was loaded successfully, false otherwise

Comment: I keep getting memory errors =(, more specifically "Unhandled exception at at 0x75BAB9BC"

Any ideas?

Comment: Try debugging maybe ^^" The code is pretty simple that shouldn't be all that hard

Comment: It's not a syntax error =( It doesn't even tell me what's wrong, it just tells me it's a memory issue.

Comment: Use the "debugger". Step by step executing until you hit the error.

Comment: Hey man, the memory error I get in on this line:

glVertex3fv(object_.vertices.at(item.vertexIndex).coords );

Any ideas why?